# To set any local notification work even after app is closed in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am building xamarin.forms app. I need to run background service that runs irrespective of application state. The background service should run even after application closes. I can use dependency service, for android but how could anybody share there code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/edsnider/Xamarin.Plugins).

You can use local notifications, so there is no external trigger needed. You can show notifications with a local date/time trigger. Besides just showing a notification right away, you can also schedule them, or schedule more at a time. If you do, whether or not the app is running at that time a notification will popup and it would look like just like any (external) notification.

Install the NuGet package on both your shared, as well as your platform projects. It seems the examples on GitHub are outdated. Add this using to the classes where you want to use it: `using Plugin.LocalNotifications;`

Then you can access the functionality through:

`CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Good morning", "Time to get up!", 1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));`

This will plan a notification for tomorrow. You can also cancel it, in the above example you give it the id of 1. You can then cancel it with:

`CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Cancel(1);`

This way you can plan a whole series, you just have to keep track of the ids yourself.

Another alternative plugin in [this one](https://github.com/aritchie/notifications) which does the same in the end but has some different features.

Comment: Notifier not accessing when I install local notification plugins

Comment: Make sure you add the right `using` in the top of your class.

Comment: There is a complete sample app in the GitHub page I have linked

Comment: still not accessing

Comment: What do you mean by accessing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131685/discussion-between-adit-kothari-and-gerald-versluis).

Comment: CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Good morning", "Time to get up!",1, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10) );
again i get error System.NotImplementedException

Comment: Did you also install the NuGet package on your platform project? Maybe you should look at the alternative plugin I have mentioned at the end.

Comment: yeah i have install on all platforms

Comment: Lets go back to the chat

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as an answer it if helped you @AditKothari

Comment: This answer is so tricky when it comes to sticky notifications , where (Which Form class ) should exactly one initialize that Plugin? , what i mean here is , notifications only come when you launchedthe page which has that Notification Plugin initialization , it doesnt work in background service

Comment: Scheduled local notification doesn't work when the app is closed